# Why does loading a gif with CGImageSource cause a memory leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a gif file in my project. I am trying to display that gif file in my `UIImageView`. Here is my code:

```
NSData* gifOriginalImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];// url of the gif file
CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)gifOriginalImageData, NULL);

NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSInteger imagesCountInGifFile = CGImageSourceGetCount(src);
CGImageRef imagesOut[imagesCountInGifFile];
for (int i = 0; i < imagesCountInGifFile; ++i) {
    [arr addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(src, i, NULL)]];
}

self.onboardingImageView.animationImages = arr;
self.onboardingImageView.animationDuration = 1.5;
self.onboardingImageView.animationRepeatCount = 2;
[self.onboardingImageView startAnimating];
```

I can display the gif file successfully with this code. However it causes a memory leak up to 250mb with 60 images. I have tried to reduce the memory with the given code however there is no success again.

```
self.onboardingImageView.animationImages = nil;
CFRelease(src);
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Edit: I have added an [image] which is a potentially leak.

Comment: what is the size of the single image ? Can't you compress those images before adding them in an array ?

Comment: The size of the image is 100kb. I think that is not too much. @TejaNandamuri

Comment: You should release `imagesOut` too since there is "ZZZCreate`

Comment: I'm not sure why you need an array for `imagesOut` – just create a `CGImage` for each iteration of your loop, wrap it a `UIImage`, then assign the `UIImage` to your array and release the `CGImage`. The general rule is for every call to a function that has the word `Create` in it, there should be a matching release call.

Comment: Releasing imagesOut did not solve the problem @Larme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a function has the word `Create` in it, that's an indication that you're responsible for releasing the memory of the thing that it returns. In this case, [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageSource/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex) of `CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex` explicitly says:

> Returns a CGImage object. You are responsible for releasing this object using CGImageRelease.

You are repeatedly calling `CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex`, but never actually releasing the `CGImage` that it returns, therefore resulting in a memory leak. The general rule of thumb is for every call to a function that has the word `Create` in it – you should have an equivalent release.

I also don't see the point in having an array of your `CGImages` (as you create an array of `UIImages`). This means that all you have to do is create your `CGImage` at each iteration of the loop, wrap it in a `UIImage`, add this image to your array and then finally release the `CGImage`. For example:

```
CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)gifOriginalImageData, NULL);

NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSInteger imagesCountInGifFile = CGImageSourceGetCount(src);
for (int i = 0; i < imagesCountInGifFile; ++i) {
    CGImageRef c = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(src, i, NULL); // create the CGImage
    [arr addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:c]]; // wrap that CGImage in a UIImage, then add to array
    CGImageRelease(c); // release the CGImage <- This part is what you're missing!
}

CFRelease(src); // release the original image source
```

Note that you should also be bridging your `gifOriginalImageData` instead of casting (I assume you're using ARC).

With the changes, the above code runs fine without any memory leaks.

Comment: Sorry for so late answer. However the leak did not disappear.

Comment: @ridvankucuk Could you update the OP with your current code? Try profiling the app in instruments for leaks, it should tell you which function call is responsible for the leak. Assuming the code you've shown in the screenshot that you added to the OP is your current code, it will indeed leak since you're not releasing the `CGImage` from `CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex`. You need to do that bit in 3 lines (create, wrap & add to array, then release), like I demonstrated above. I'm happy to clarify my answer if you wish :)

Comment: @ridvankucuk: just like `originaluser2` is saying, you need to do that code in 3 lines like he/she suggested, not in one line like you've done. You need to `CGImageRelease()` the result of `CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex()` to balance things out.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to work with an array of NSData vs. an array of UIImage. Image data is compressed by default and working with a UIImage decompresses the data.

Also, UIImage has some caching under the hood that can be hard on memory.

Michael Behan wrote a great blog post on the topic: http://mbehan.com/post/78399605333/uiimageview-animation-but-less-crashy

And he wrote a helpful library (MIT License) to prevent this from happening: https://github.com/mbehan/animation-view